# What's wrong with this JavaScript/HTML

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I think I just need a second pair of eyes on this one. The div's `onclick` event doesn't seem to be working. Any ideas?

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
 <head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title="My First Program"/>

 <script type="text/javascript">
      window.onload = function(){
           window.alert("If you see me then the page has loaded"); 
           click(); 
      }

      //we do programming here 
      /*because
        it is 
        fun*/
      window.alert("Helo World!"); 
     
      function click(){
           window.alert("CLICK!!!!");
      }
      

 </script>

 </head>
 <body>
      <div>This web page will run my first program</div>
      <!--this will be awesome-->
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <div id="d1" onclick="click()">Click me</div>
 </body>
```

Also, for the record, this is not my first program.

Comment: get Firebug to step through it....

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/e3GTn/ seems to be working....

Comment: That doesn't work for me.  I know this doesn't answer the question directly, but why do you want to have this as an inline script?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

your html is malformed. the title tag needs to look like this:

```
<title>My First Program</title>
```

Also, you seem to have a naming conflict because you named your function the same thing as a built-in function. rename your 'click' function to 'myclick' or something else.

Once you fix that, everything else should be good.

When something is going weird, the first thing you should always do is validate your markup.

http://validator.w3.org/check

Here is the complete, working version of the markup.

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
 <head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>My First Program</title>

 <script type="text/javascript">
      window.onload = function(){
           window.alert("If you see me then the page has loaded"); 
           click(); 
      }

      //we do programming here 
      /*because
        it is 
        fun*/
      window.alert("Helo World!"); 

      function myclick(){
           window.alert("CLICK!!!!");
      }


 </script>

 </head>
 <body>
      <div>This web page will run my first program</div>
      <!--this will be awesome-->
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <div id="d1" onclick="myclick()">Click me</div>
 </body>
```

Comment: Got tix to see Pennywise and Lagwagon next month...stoked!

Comment: @Madbreaks You lucky bastard...last time I got to see them was about 13 years ago... lol

Comment: I edited all of the HTML to be correct and was still not able to get the click event to fire in Chrome.

Comment: One second, i'll update this post with the complete HTML i have which works fine in chrome. you probably didn't rename the function call in the onclick on the div.

Comment: Oof, time to go home, I think.  Completely missed that line in your answer.  Apologies!

Answer (score 0):

Every time I see a question like this anywhere, the typical answer I give is "don't use the Netscape model for event handling".

Give this a read - http://www.quirksmode.org/js/introevents.html

Update:  Looks like "click" isn't a very good name for a function, since it's already registered for events and such, which is likely why it didn't work.  I should have caught that.